# HTML DOM not rendering open attribute value inside react application

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Simple react application trying to add open attribute in span tag its not rendering in html output

Same is working as expected in simple HTML page

HTML Sample: https://codepen.io/karthikeyan-sivagurunathan/pen/qBKvVgQ

[image]

```
<div>
      <span open="(" close=")">
        <span>x2+y2</span>
      </span>
      <span>=z2</span>
    </div>
```

React Sample: https://codepen.io/karthikeyan-sivagurunathan/pen/vYrPWQw

[image]

Comment: Does it work correctly if you set it to a different string? E.g. `open=“some string”`.

Comment: No its not working if I add any value in open attribute

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what are those open and close attributes for span tag...
but maybe you want something like this?

```
<details open={false}>
  <summary>2+2</summary>
  <span>=4</span>
</details>
```

Comment: I need to process some operation based on the string value set inside the open attribute.
When I check same string is populated in normal HTML and Angular page. This is not coming in React application. Just want to check how to render string inside open attribute.